# jQuery - Dynamic Tabs via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xhtml

Does anyone know how this effect is named and how to
recreate it in jQuery (without that library*)?:

http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php

Click on the links on the left,
can u see how tabs are created dynamically and contet is loaded via Ajax?

one feature I miss in this example: rearrange tabs (sortable)

*without that library = without the library/plugin I linkted to.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer to that is to use jQueryUI.

Their Tabs widget supports everything you need: [Adding tabs dynamically](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-add), Loading content in ajax, [sortables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#sortable).

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs